# Is this the definition for a list using cons?

Tags: list, functional-programming, cons

In a paper I see a definition for a list (`T` is any type you want):

```
listof T ::= Nil | Cons T (listof T)
```

I think this says:

List of type `T` is defined as either `Nil` or the result of the function `cons` applied to a list of type `T`, where `cons` links the list with another list (the remainder - which could be `nil`).

Is this an accurate description?

Comment: The syntax is similar to GADTs in Haskell: `data Listof t = Nil | Cons t (Listof t)`. `Nil` is of type `Listof t` and `Cons` is of type `t -> Listof t -> Listof t`.

Comment: "*`cons` links the list with another list*" - No! `Cons` links a **single element** of type `T` with another list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is how [Lisp lists](http://shrager.org/llisp/3.html) were constructed.

This is the *linked list*. Since a `Nil` or `Cons` is an object in memory, we thus have an object for every element in the list. That object has - given it is a `Cons` - two references: one to the element the list holds at that position, and one to the next node in the linked list.

So if you store a list `(1,4,2,5)`, then internally, it is stored as:

```
+---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
| o | o---->| o | o---->| o | o---->| o | o----> Nil
+-|-+---+   +-|-+---+   +-|-+---+   +-|-+---+
  v           v           v           v
  1           4           2           5
```

Or you can construct it like `Cons 1 (Cons 4 (Cons 2 (cons 4 Nil)))`.

The concept of a Lisp list is quite popular in both *functional* and *logic* programming languages.

Working with linked lists usually requires to write different algorithms than working with arrays and arraylists. Obtaining the *k*-th element will require *O(k)* time, so usually one aims to prevent that. Therefore one usually iterates through the list and for instance emits certain elements (given these for instance satisfy a given predicate).

Comment: Can you recommend a reference that helped you for further reading?